# Do something based on some conditions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have to do an operation in python only if some criteria meets.

Suppose I want to this operation :

```
data2["Comment"].str.contains("\\berror\\b", case = False,na=False))
```

when below condition meets

```
data2['SR Ticket num'].isin(data1['SR Ticket num']) &  ( data1['flag'] != 'yes')
```

I am writing the below code and getting error

```
rule5 = (data2["Comment"].str.contains("\\berror\\b", case = False,na=False)) np.where(data2['SR Ticket num'].isin(data1['SR Ticket num']) &  ( data1['flag'] != 'yes')
```

Please suggest how can I perform this operations when some criteria meets. I tried but got invalid syntax error.

Comment: You have two statements on the same line: `rule5 = ...` and `np.where(data2...`. If you _mean_ to have them on the same line, you must separate them with a semicolon.

Comment: @JohnColeman Those are dataframes though

Comment: You will need something before `np.where`

Comment: So basically u mean three different conditions. I'd recommend you write them on separate rows and combine with &

Comment: What is `data2`?  I see a `numpy` tag, but `contains` isn't a numpy method, nor a Python string one.

Answer (score 0):

An example how the conditions can be

```
data1 = {'flag':'no', 'SR Ticket num': 56}
data2 = {"Comment": "berror", "SR Ticket num": 56}

na = None 

if "berror"  in data2["Comment"]:
    # berror found in data2 Comment
    # continue here 
    na = True 
else:
    # berror not found
    # continue here 
    na = False 


if data2['SR Ticket num'] == data1["SR Ticket num"] and data1['flag'] != 'yes':
    # data2 SR Ticket num is equal with data1 SR Ticket num and data1 flag is not set to yes 
    # continue here 
    pass
```